# Why my update(Patch Request) won't save anything in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I was training for my homework with a laravel project and here's my problem:

I've got a database with `Event` name and bunch of relation to this database, two of them is `events_news` and `event_gallery` which news update working fine buy gallery just won't work and I did it in same way with news, I've tried with postman, and I only get Updated Response but nothing gonna change.

Here's My Event Model :

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::creating(function ($event){
        $event->slug = str_slug($event->name);
    });
}

public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}

protected $with = ['galleries','news'];

public function news(){
    return $this->hasMany(EventNews::class);
}

public function galleries()
{
    return $this->hasMany(EventGallery::class);
}

public function getPathAttribute()
{
    return "/admin/events/$this->slug";
}
```

And Here's My Gallery and News Model: I was using guarded for both before, but I've added fillable to the gallery to see if it's work or not.

```
class EventGallery extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = ['event_id', 'url', 'body', 'flag'];

  public function event()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo(Event::class);
    }
}

 class EventNews extends Model
 {

     protected $guarded = [];

     public function event()
       {
        return $this->belongsTo(Event::class);
       }
}
```

And here's My Controller :

```
public function update(Request $request, Event $event, EventGallery $eventGallery)
{
    /I've tried this and got same result
    $eventGallery->update($request->all());

    /I've tried this and still got the same result
    $eventGallery->update(
        [
            'url' => $request->url,
            'body' => $request->body,
            'flag' => $request->flag,

        ]
    );
    return response('Updated', Response::HTTP_ACCEPTED);
}
```

Api :

`Route::apiResource('/admin/events/{event}/gallery', 'Events\EventsPictureController');`

I'll test with a real data in the database with `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/admin/events/international-2019/gallery/2`

and it says Updated, but nothing gonna change. please help me to find my problem.

> I've checked Event and imported correctly not Facade/Event.

And this is for SPA app with vue.js. and instructor injected Event in the controller so this is why I've done it like what u saw.

Comment: Are you sure your request contains key/values in the body?

Comment: @PtrTon i'm not sure what u mean... i've tried other ways didn't worked. and tried above api with postman, and still got same error. but i tried to use Resource instead of 'Updated' and it gave me null. but i don't get what is the problem since everything is working fine in other table.

Comment: have you tried `dd($request->all());` to see if the request contains values? Maybe the issue is the request which is being sent to the controller, instead of the way the controller handles the request.

Comment: @PtrTon well I've tried this and I've got values of my inputs. I've got all of them in array. is it possible for u to check it by remote app?

Comment: that's probably not a good idea. Just make sure to provide us with as much relevant information as possible. Then someone on stackoverflow will probably push you in the right direction.

Comment: @PtrTon i know what u say, and It's right, but It's just so weird to see what's the problem. I've used Custom Request and etc... Still can't get what is the problem. don't u think anything is happening is in Model relation? because i did it without injecting Event in function and with fail($id), but i don't get why this is going so weird...

Comment: You could check if changing the model without mass assignment works. So something like `$eventGallery->url = 'some-test-url'; $eventGallery->save();`. Then check if the record is updated in the database

Comment: @PtrTon with '$eventGallery->url = 'some-test-url'; $eventGallery->save();' well this is going to create another data without fail(), for me.

Comment: @PtrTon I'm not sure, but don't u think the problem is in relationship?
i can, get data, and create with it, but somehow i think it's going to fail where he's going to find the id.

Comment: From what I can see the model is found since `$eventGallery` contains the model, correct? The [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding) seems okay as well. The [mass update](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#updates) is working fine as well from what I heard. The model relationships should not be affected since you're only updating the `EventGallery`. Seems the issue is in a spot we didn't see yet, maybe check if a middleware is interfering? Otherwise try to isolate the issue by taking out moving parts and trying again.

Comment: @PtrTon thanks for following and helping my, i've found my problem and answer it, i'll be happy if u have any idea why this is matter. check my answer because the only reason i think i might get a clue about why i had this problem, is just function name in my Event Model. which it was $gallery and i was using $eventGallery in controller.

Comment: Glad you found it in the end :-)

Comment: @PtrTon still it's weird for me, i've checked i had same problem again in video table, and it fixed with changing to $video again. I've got some clue when i tried to use `$ev = Event::find($event);` to make sure i'm getting data, then i checked and saw there's base on videoes & gallery. so i just changed at it got fixed. i hope i found what exactly happened here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after digging my problem was in Controller
I've just changed `public function update(Request $request, Event $event, EventGallery $eventGallery)`

To `public function update(Request $request, Event $event, EventGallery $gallery)`

Still looking for the reason why this happened. maybe it's because i called gallery in my Event Model

as u can see in  top i typed galleries, but since i was trying anything, i changed function model to gallery which it didn't helped, but when i changed $eventGallery, it worked.